# How to get sharepoint file from document library if I know file url (JSOM)?

Tags: jsom

I have url like "http://test/site/subsite/docslibrary/filename.doc"
I need to get one of custom columns of file in future, so need access this file in sharepoint.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function retrieveListItemFromUrl() {        
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var url = "http://test/site/subsite/docslibrary/filename.doc";
    var f = web.getFileByUrl(url);          
    context.load(f, 'ListItemAllFields');           
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function () { retrieveListItemFromUrlResult(f); }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onErrorHandler)
    );
}

function retrieveListItemFromUrlResult(f) {     
    var item = f.get_listItemAllFields();   
    console.log(item.get_fieldValues().ColumnName);
}

function onErrorHandler(sender,args)
{
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

You should replace the value of url variable and the ColumnName in retrieveListItemFromUrlResult function to match your data.
Also, the code should run in context of the web that contains the document library. If that is not the case, you should create the context object providing the url of the web that contains the document library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `getFileByServerRelativeUrl` method to get the file and then load the list item to get all properties as below;

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
var file = context.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl("http://test/site/subsite/docslibrary/filename.doc");   //get file
context.load(file,'ListItemAllFields'); 

context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields();
    var customColumn = listItem.get_fieldValues().customColumn;  //use internal name of column
    console.log(customColumn);
},function(sender,args){
    console.log("something went wrong " + args.get_message());
});
```